# How to test an android game made in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: android, unreal-4, testing, unreal

I have made a android game in unreal engine 4 version 4.12.4 and I want to test it on a real android device and i do have an android tablet but i don't know how to get the exported project onto the tablet for testing so can someone tell me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressuming you have the android sdk installed:

Put your phone into developer mode plug it into the computer, and enable adb

Open command prompt and navigate to the adb folder inside the sdk

```
adb devices
```

after this type:

```
adb install apkname.apk
```

or the other way enable allow installs from unkown sources
put the apk on your phone navigate to it and then open it and install it that way but the first option is easy enough to make an install script for when you update it.

**Hope this helps**

Jordan

Comment: So the phone has a command prompt? Sorry if i'm a noob but well i am

Comment: No you use your computer, with your phone plugged in, and... we've all got to start somewhere, give me 5 mins I'll write a file for you to run

Comment: I'll link you hear this will be more helpful: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html find isntall in there aslong as you have somebasic knolege on how to use the command line your ok

Comment: Thanks i'll have a read through this, it's finally nice to meet a person thats willing to help noobs

Comment: No probs, let me know how you got on, Like i said we've all got to start somewhere i know how intimidating it was when i first started programming 6 years ago

Comment: When i typed in "adb install apkname.apk" once the packaged file was on the tablet when i tried to start the program it said that there was no OBB file